# Show popup on hover if text is long

Tags: css

I have this codepen and this works for me except for one thing. I want the popup to appear only if the text width exceeds the its container width. But this codepen shows it everytime. How do I do this?

Comment: How should we know? Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You are not quite clear in your question, but if you want to check if your text overflows and show tooltip then, use code like this.

```js
div = document.querySelector("#div");

if (div.scrollWidth > div.offsetWidth) {
 div.setAttribute("title", "heyyy")
} else {
 div.removeAttribute("title")
}
```

```css
#div {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  Helooooooooooo
</div>
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yLbh75x1/1/ 
Just change text of the div to see the difference.